# Ошибка при компиляции бота для вк с dialogflow python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, импорт

хочу изучить работу с dialogflow вместе с vk_api, но при компиляции этого кода(работаю с pythonanywhere)

```
from flask import Flask, request, json
import requests
import random
import vk_api
import apiai, json
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="Токен для вк")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST"])
# Обработка команд
def main():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if data["type"] == "confirmation":
        return " "
    elif data["type"] == "message_new":
        object = data["object"]
        id = object["peer_id"]
        body = object["text"]
        request = apiai.ApiAI('токен для dialogflow').text_request()
        request.lang = 'ru' 
        request.session_id = 'BatlabAIBot'
        request.query = body.lower() 
        responseJson = json.loads(request.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))
        response = responseJson['result']['fulfillment']['speech'] 
        if response:
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message":response, "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        else:
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message":"Чево?", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    return "ok"
```

возникает такая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/minieventbot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/AI (1).py", line 4, in <module>
    import apiai, json
  File "./apiai/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .VAD import VAD
  File "./apiai/VAD.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/minieventbot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/AI (1).py", line 4, in <module>
    import apiai, json
  File "./apiai/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .VAD import VAD
  File "./apiai/VAD.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/minieventbot/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/AI (1).py", line 5, in <module>
    import apiai, json
  File "./apiai/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .VAD import VAD
  File "./apiai/VAD.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 16, in <module>
    add_docstring(
RuntimeError: implement_array_function method already has a docstring
```

Comment: я новичок в python и не очень внимателен, так что возможно я сделал что-то очень глупое, извините :)